# ReactiveMongo socket disconnect

Tags: sockets, reactivemongo

Logs:

`OUT 08:52:27.158 [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem - The primary is unavailable, is there a network problem?`

`ERR reactivemongo.core.errors.GenericDriverException: MongoError['socket disconnected']`

`ERR at reactivemongo.core.actors.MongoDBSystem$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$applyOrElse$30.apply(actors.scala:390) ~[org.reactivemongo.reactivemongo_2.11-0.11.6.jar:0.11.6]`

Our rest api, written in Scala (utilising the Spray and Akka frameworks) is deployed on a cloud.

We've tried setting the KeepAlive flag in `ReactiveMongoOptions` and then implemented a Jenkins job to periodically hit the database to keep it alive. However since adding these we've not seen the issue reoccur.

Rather than assume this has fixed it, before pushing to production, we are trying to reproduce the issue. Any ideas on what may be the cause or how we can reproduce this?

Comment: How do you ger connection? Code?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and it appears to be network related and not code related. A devops problem...

Comment: did you finnd a solution?